# How to get the files that were changed, added or modified in the repository directory

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

Is it possible to get all the changed/added/removed files from a repository, and then stage those files? If yes, how?

I was doing something like this:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("dir/repo", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    repo.Stage(file);
}
```

However, it does not satisfy me because I stage all of the untracked files. But I want to stage all of the modified/added/deleted files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get all the changed/added/removed files from a repository, and then stage those files? If yes, how?

*"Use the wildcard, Luke!"* ;-)

`repo.Stage("*")` will mimic `git add --all` (from git **[documentation](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/docs/git-add)**: *"Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching  but also where the index already has an entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree."*)

See **[CanMimicGitAddAll()](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/IndexFixture.cs#L447-L467)** test from `IndexFixture.cs` for some additional insights.

Comment: @Alexandre: Did that answer provide you with any help?

Answer (score -1):

You can use git command line tools to get lists of changed/added/removed files. Just Google it and you will find plenty of resources.

Take a look at how to run a command line tool and get the output as a string:

> [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

I think that's all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not what I needed. I figured that each file has a custom state that can be retrieved using `repo.RetrieveStatus("file.txt")`. Then I just check if the status is added, modified or removed, and then stage it.