# how to execute shell command through c#

Tags: c#, bash

I have a command line which run a c# executale. while it's running, I'd like the c# executable to input on the command line some command. I want this because I want to know in the command line which commands were called and the results.

I also need to fetch the results.

The commands the c# executable generate may be things from
cd ..
to execute another executable through
mono fetch.exe

without a process
[How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

something like

Console.WriteLine
but which would execute the line in the same time since the exe is executed throught the window

Comment: there are tons of questions that answer this.

Comment: they mostly say to use a process, but I don't want it doesn't give the same result

Comment: if there are tons can you give me one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell commands cannot be executed within the same process. If you really want to execute direct, arbitrary shell commands, you can just run `cmd /c <command>` with `Process.Start` for any command. Note that `&&`, `||`, `&` can be used to make a more interesting single command. (If you want to stream multiple commands to the same process, you can even send shell commands via stdout but this is more effort to set up).

However you shouldn't need to run shell commands because the equivalent functionality exists in C# and is more efficient than shell commands because shell commands are interpreted (whereas C# is compiled). For example, you can use `startInfo.WorkingDirectory` (from [process.StartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to emulate the effect of "`cd ..`"