# Should I use Thread or Thread pool for file downloading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know this kind of question was asked many time but I really can't decide what should I use between `Thread` or `Thread pool`.

I'm creating download manager program which can download simultaneously.

I used to use `Thread` for downloading each file and observation for queuing download but there are weird problems when I want to stop downloading(call to `Thread.Abort`).

Now, I'm using `Task.Run`, everything work fine but I'm worrying about suitability because it may run from a minute to hours(many people say about Thread pool with cpu-intensive work but none say about long running like this).

So, what should I use for long running operation like this?

Edit, I use HttpWebRequest, HttpWebResponse and Stream for downloading because I want to calculate BPS, ETA and throttling(obtain from HttpWebResponse).

Edit2, I use WPF as UI, calculate and rise about 4 `PropertyChanged` event, I'm so sorry that I didn't provide enough information at the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I use Thread or Thread pool for downloading

Neither.

For an efficient approach, use asynchronous I/O. How exactly depends on the API but several interfaces are now compatible with async/await.

For instance,
 - `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync(Uri, String)`      is already efficent
 - `WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(Uri, String)`  is easier to use

With the stream from HttpWebResponse you can use (Fx 4.5 and up)

```
Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, 
  int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this before, I use HttpWebRequest, HttpWebResponse and Stream for downloading because I want to calculate BPS, ETA and throttling(obtain from HttpWebResponse).so, with these work does it cause responsiveness suffers or I can use ConfigureAwait to solve it?

Comment: Agreed, but using [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) is usually recommended over WebClient.

Comment: As I said, the details depend on the API.  WebClient was just an easy (for me) example. I'll edit.

Comment: with asynchronous await, Doesn't it cause sluggishness as responsiveness suffers from any calculation? if it cause Can I use ConfigureAwait(false) to solve it?

Comment: That all depends on the surrounding application, you don't give us much to work with. The CPU usage for the calculations should be negligible.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I didn't provide enough information, I tried await on I/O operation and it cause poorly responsiveness, maybe becaues I must calculate and rise about 4 update event(WPF) every time ReadAsync return , but I can fix it by `ConfigureAwait(false)` on hight level method. so, it run on thread in thread pool again, is this difference from `Task.Run` without `ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: You could use 1 or even a few (pool) threads, just not 1 per download when there are many. Reporting progress is a separate issue but the WPF databinding is threadsafe, just use a ViewModel.

Comment: Thank you, finally I knew what cause poorly responsiveness, it because I implemented `ReadAsync` in wrong manner(synchronous block).  I haven't noticed this before because I used thread in thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project that combined [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) with c# via rpc. This worked exceedingly well. Whether your leverage aria2 or simply glean from its concepts is up to you, but I encourage you to at least take a look.

**hint**
In order to get peak performance, your file server would need to support http range requests.

Here's the [manual](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/)

To invoke it, you simply need the executable in your path. Then you invoke it.

```
aria2c "http://host/file.zip"
```

Here's how to [invoke a process from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results).

Comment: I already looked into it but as I'm newbie, I really don't know how to use it with C# program, Can you give me a hint so that I can research about using external utility like this?