# adding a user input into c# process

Tags: c#, process, cmd, ping

So im trying to make a ip pinger to see if a server is online and have got this so far i would like it so that the user can in put a ip on there own from a text box. but keep getting a error on the start part.

> Error CS1501  No overload for method 'Start' takes 3 arguments

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("cmd", "/k ping"  + flatTextBox1.Text ,"-t");
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You aren't matching any of the [valid signatures for `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues here:

First, the `"-t"` is used as third parameter because of the comma before it. You should add it to the string you're building with `"/k"` in combination with the IP address.

Next, given the textbox text is `"127.0.0.1"` this will currently end up as: `/k ping127.0.0.1`

So you might just add a space in between the "ping" and the IP.

**BUT:** you should not use cmd.exe for this, consider to use the [Ping class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) from the .NET framework.

Comment: Very helpful I was aiming  for a user to input a ip address into the text box then lunch the cmd with a button and automatically write a line saying "ping 127.0.0.0 -t" would that work ?

Comment: Yes it will, just use your code line: `Process.Start("cmd", "/k ping 127.0.0.1 -t");`

Comment: But where abouts would I need to put the +flat text.Text so that it dosnt give me a error

Comment: `Process.Start("cmd", "/k ping " + flatTextBox1.Text + " -t");`

Comment: Now the question is, can you get any info back into your program if you are able to start the ping as a process?  As stated in the edited answer, maybe you should look at the ping class in the .NET framework if your goal is to check to see if a server is online.

Comment: You mean to read the stdout of that process, I think. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results

Answer (score 1):

Try using ProcessStartInfo:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
startInfo.Arguments = "/k ping " + flatTextBox1.Text + " -t";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```