# Running Command Line from C# without Window and Getting Output

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to run a command line script from C#. I want it to run without a shell and place the output into my string output. It doesn't like the p.StartInfo line. What am I doing wrong? I am not running a file like p.StartInfo.FileName = "YOURBATCHFILE.bat" like [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results). I need to set the "CMD.exe" and command line string. I have tried p.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText); but that gives me the error: "Memer 'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string,string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead."

```
    string ipAddress;
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    string strCmdText;
    strCmdText = "tracert -d " + ipAdress;
    p.StartInfo("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Can you provide a program to us that builds? I'm 99% sure this one doesn't

Comment: "It doesn't like the p.StartInfo line." Exactly what is the error?

Comment: No, it doesn't and won't run, because the IP addresses are specific to my machine, and the p.StartInfo won't compile anyways. It says it "cannot be used like a method".

Comment: Uhuh. You're using a property like a method.

Comment: Non-invocable member 'System.Diagnostics.Process.StartInfo' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Yes, obviously, and I am wondering how I set the CMD.exe and command line arguments.

Comment: That's pretty self explanatory. First of all, you have `ipAdress` spelled wrong. Second of all, you're using StartInfo() like a method

Comment: I saw that one, but it doesn't answer how to add "CMD.exe" and then my command. I have no file.

Comment: Your answer is the [second answer to the other question which this question is a duplicate of](http://stackoverflow.com/a/206366/1730559). You don't even need "cmd.exe" anyway.

Comment: I didn't see that, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code gives me the correct ouput.

```
const string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
Process process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/C tracert -d " + ipAddress
    }
};
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
if(process.HasExited)
{
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: That was the format I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It gives me the error "StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet."

Comment: @Sean Try the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `StartInfo` incorrectly. Have a look at documentation for [ProcessStartInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Process.Start Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your code should look something like this:

```
string ipAddress;
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
string strCmdText;
strCmdText = "/C tracert -d " + ipAdress;

// Correct way to launch a process with arguments
p.StartInfo.FileName="CMD.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments=strCmdText;
p.Start();


string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Also, note that I added `/C` argument to `strCmdText`. As per `cmd /?` help:

```
/C Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates.
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It gives me the error "Member 'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string,string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead."