# How to execute a command and get its output

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I've been learning a few things about ASP for the past few days.
I wanted to convert this PHP code line into ASP but I'm kinda stuck with it:

```
$online = exec('netstat -a -n |find "5816" |find "ESTABLISHED" /c') +1;
```

I have tried creating a variable to store the data but unable to figure out how to check the port 5816 and count the amount of connections.
Help is appreciated!

It should be basically a command to be run in cmd to check the port and no. of connections established by it !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Executing a command getting its output

You can use this code to execute the above command:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/C netstat -a -n |find \"5816\" |find \"ESTABLISHED\" /c",
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};
process.Start();
// Now read the value, parse to int and add 1 (from the original script)
int online = int.Parse(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()) + 1;
process.WaitForExit();
```

This code starts the cmd.exe executable. Using the /C argument, you can give it the command you want to execute

**Source:** [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results), [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Comment: This answer works for executing "built-in" commands, but doesn't seem to work when running an arbitary executable.