# How can I export collection to Json file?

Tags: c#, mongodb, export

I have a collection in a database, I want to export it to a json file in c#.
I know the command that can be executed through the mongo shell.
Has this command - `mongoexport --collection = movies --db = director --out = movies.json`

But I'm looking for the c # code to do that.
Would appreciate help.

Comment: Both `System.Text.Json` and `Newtonsoft.Json` have methods for serialising objects as JSON - for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0.  Once you have got your collection using the MongoDB C# driver, simply use one of those.  Then when you have the JSON, you can write it to a file using `System.IO`.

Comment: You can run the `mongoexport` as a system command from C# as in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36256114/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-its-output