# Redirect cmd gradlew output to C#

Tags: c#, logging, gradle, cmd

I'm calling `cmd /C gradlew assembleRelease` from C# code. I'm trying to display the gradle output log into the C# console (or file). This code is from a nuget package running in Unity.

Attempts so far:

```
cmd /C gradlew assembleRelease > gradleLog.txt
Log(File.ReadAllText("gradleLog.txt"))
```

I just get the C# stacktrace. Not the gradle log.

Tried this answer with the same result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/206347

Is it possible to get the whole gradle output to the console or a file in such a scenario? Let me know if you guys need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how cradle works but calling it like the example from the link should work, if you read the output and the errors after the `p.WaitForExit();` call.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = " assembleRelease";
p.StartInfo.FileName = "gradlew";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

And maybe you should add some additional arguments for [cradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html):

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i -s assembleRelease";
```