# How can I Integrate Python version 3 with .Net

Tags: c#, python, .net, opencv, face-recognition

I am Integrating Python script to .Net and I am using IronPython package that's available for .Net developers in Visual Studio. My Python code contains packages like face_recognition, glob, opencv. I am getting an error when I'am running this python script although the simple Python is running in PyCharm. Can anyone know what I am doing wrong? Please give me the answer that I should do.

These packages I am using and later I am using it by calling them:

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import glob

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

all_images = glob.glob('images/*.jpg')
```

And this is my Code which is in Visual Studio: (Making a Console App)

```
            var py = Python.CreateEngine();

            py.ExecuteFile("C:\\Users\\Hp\\PycharmProjects\\final_face\\example.py");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

And the error I am getting by the Visual Studio is:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException' in Microsoft.Scripting.dll

The program '[23408] PythonDotNet.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: are you using the same Python version for both the native (CPython) and IronPython interpreters? There are many differences between v2 and v3.

Comment: No, IronPython latest version is 2.7.9 and CPython is 3.6.6.

Comment: Then you found the problem, IronPython 3 is not ready for production, see https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3

Comment: Instead of using IronPython you can execute the Python script in a command line and parse the output, see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @AlexanderPope Thanks man your suggested link has my answer. I am answering to my question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because that function is not what you want.

Create a new Console App Project called RunPython.csproj. In the main sub, write:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var py = Python.CreateRuntime();
    py.ExecuteFile();
}
```

After that, you can build your project to generate an ".exe" file. In Console or a shell, write:

```
RunPython.exe "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\final_face\example.py"
```

You can visit [this site](http://putridparrot.com/blog/hosting-ironpython-in-a-c-application/) for more examples.

Comment: No it is not working man. It throwing an error and showing build failed in the Error List.

Answer (score 3):

IronPython 3 is not ready for production so Instead of using IronPython you can execute the Python script in a command line and parse the output:

```
  class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              Program p = new Program();
              p.butPython();
          }

      public void butPython()
      {
          var hello = "Calling Python...";

          Tuple<String, String> python = GoPython(@"C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\final_face\final.py");
          hello = python.Item1; // Show result.
          Console.WriteLine(hello);
          Console.ReadLine();
      }

      public Tuple<String, String> GoPython(string pythonFile, string moreArgs = "")
      {
          ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
          PSI.FileName = "py.exe";
          PSI.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" {1}", pythonFile, moreArgs);
          PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
          PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
          PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
          PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
          using (Process process = Process.Start(PSI))
          using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
          {
              string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Error(s)!!
              string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // What we want.
              return new Tuple<String, String>(result, stderr);
          }
      }
  }
```