# Python shell interactive input output from .NET/C#

Tags: c#, python, .net, shell

I'm looking for a way to directly interact with the python shell from .NET/C#.  I know that I can run the python script using process in .NET, but I'm looking for a way to do the interactive way as we do with **python shell**.

For eg.,

```
>>> a=10
>>> b=20
>>> a+b
30
>>>
```

I want to input such 'a=10','b=20','a+b' as string from C# or .NET to the python shell and read-out the python output '30' from the shell.  If any one knows idea to do this, please help.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

Comment: @Innominatum I have tried the *Process* and *StartInfo* but it doesn't helps for the shell.  It works for command line but not for shell.  Shell goes into some other mode where this process and startinfo doesn't works.