# How execute commands of cmd in c# and return the values

Tags: c#, cmd

How i can execute commands of cmd and return the values of this.
For example, i execute the command **Ipconfig** and return a list of interface available

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/206347/1274820

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why would you use these crazy hacks when there are windows libraries, WinAPI functions and nuget packages? Using any of those will be as simple as Library.GetInterfacesList().

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands) post has a great answer. It also shows how you can run commands without the command prompt popping up.

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "/C copy /b Image1.jpg + Archive.rar Image2.jpg";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

Comment: OP wants values to be returned , i think

Comment: @kas Oops, you're right. Good thing it's already answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Process.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8) method to run command-line commands, capture the console outputs, and parse it to get your return values. It's a bit messy but it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58286629/1274820

Comment: Yes, that's the same method.

Comment: Yes - I was just adding some code for you