# How to chain Linux commands in .net 5

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-5

is there any way to use .NET 5 Process class to use chain linux commands like I would to in a terminal?

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
```

The command above would return the memory the system has, I can run cat with "/proc/meminfo" as an argument, but how could I do it all at once?

EDIT: Tried to set the filename to "/bin/bash" and to pass "cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal" as arguments but it still doesn't work, throwing the error `/usr/bin/cat: /usr/bin/cat: cannot execute binary file`

EDIT 2: Found a solution, here's the code that works

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/sh";
        string cmd = "cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-c \"{cmd}\"";

        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: [This is for windows but might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

Comment: @AliK that doesn't help, sorry, I know how to run a command with the process class, the only problem I'm facing is chaining the commands in Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/sh";
        string cmd = "cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-c \"{cmd}\"";

        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```