# C# execute command line and failed to get result

Tags: c#, command-line

As title.  I want to do something to DOCKER on a server with no DOCKER DESKTOP easily, so I've read [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results) , and I make my code as this:

```
CmdProcess = new Process();
CmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
CmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;  
CmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
CmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; 
CmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
CmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
CmdProcess.Start();
CmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("/K docker images");
output = CmdProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
if (output != string.Empty)
{
    MessageBox.Show(output, "Docker Image Show", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No data", "Docker Image Show", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

and I got stuck at the line to get output value, no response, just like running into a infinite loop.  Could someone guide me to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You're not starting the program you think you're starting.

```
CmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
// ...
CmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("/K docker images");
```

What this does is start a shell prompt (*cmd.exe*) and then send the string "/K docker images" to the input. When I try doing that manually, I get

```
'/k' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The reason you are not seeing that message is probably because this is printed to the standard error, not the standard output, and you're not creating a window (which may be useful to do as long as you're debugging). **Make sure you also read the error stream!** To read both streams at the same time, you'll need to do it asynchronously as shown in this [answer by Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47382540/2920343).

What you need to do is either 'type in' the command that you want at the prompt:

```
CmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
CmdProcess.Start();
// ...
CmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("docker images");
//                                ^^^ no /K here
```

or better, **use `StartInfo.Arguments` to pass in the argument**:

```
CmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
CmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K docker images";
CmdProcess.Start();
```

Also, note that `cmd` is never going to exit when you use `/K`, you may want to **use `/C` instead**:

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute the docker images command and read its output in your C# application. The issue with your code is that you're using "/K" with WriteLine, which is incorrect. You can fix your code by using /C flag and passing it as an argument to cmd.exe:

```
string output;
Process CmdProcess = new Process();
CmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
CmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C docker images";
CmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
CmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
CmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
CmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
CmdProcess.Start();

output = CmdProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = CmdProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
CmdProcess.WaitForExit();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
{
    MessageBox.Show(error, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
{
    MessageBox.Show(output, "Docker Image Show", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No data", "Docker Image Show", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```